# Gremlinepipeline Edges between two Vertex

Tags: java, orientdb

To check the edge between the vertex using Gremline pipeline in java code?
I am able to create the edges but if we give the same vertex again the new edge will be created. I want to create a unique edge between the 2 vertex.
Any help?
I am using orientDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a unique index on the Edge class that will give you that constraint

```
create class Foo extends V
create class FooEdge extends E
create property FooEdge.in LINK
create property FooEdge.out LINK

create index FooEdge_in_out on FooEdge (out,in) unique
insert into Foo set name = 'Foo1'
insert into Foo set name = 'Foo2'
create edge FooEdge from (select from Foo where name = 'Foo1') to (select from Foo where name = 'Foo2')
/* fail */
create edge FooEdge from (select from Foo where name = 'Foo1') to (select from Foo where name = 'Foo2')
```